# Change cell color when not equal previous cell

Tags: excel, vba

Looking for a way to change cell color and font when the cell value differs from the value in the previous cell.  Sounds easy, but there is a twist.
If the value in A2 is not equal to the value in A1, I want to change the cell/font colors in cell A2, for example, fill the cell with blue and change font to white, bold.   Then, as the formula/macro progresses through the rows, and eventually finds that another cell has a value that is not equal to the preceding cell, say A12 is not equal to A11, I want to change the fill/font colors for A12.  I want to essentially flip-flop the fill/font colors when the not equal condition occurs.  Say I set the fill/font on A1 as Blue/white-bold.
When the first not equal condition occurs, I change the fill/font in A? to light-red/black-bold.  Then, on the next not equal condition, change the fill/font for that cell back to the original values, Blue/white-bold.

Comment: Ok - what have you attempted?

Comment: Conditional Formatting?

Comment: you need 2 levels of conditionnal formatting. One to check if the value is the same as the previous value, and one to check what kind of conditionnal formatting has been used last. your question,s formulation is very hard to understand, as you can see both answers don't really address the 2 sides of the question. You should add a screenshot of what you want to happen.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the cells to be formatted (here it's A2:A15)
2. Add a formula-based Conditional Formatting rule using the formula:

   `=MOD(SUM((A$2:A2<>A$1:A1)*1),2)=0`

Adjust the formula to suit your actual range, and make sure the top cell is the "active" one (select the range from the top down, not from the bottom up) when applying the format: that way the formula will adjust correctly for the rest of the cells getting the format.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question can be found with Conditional Formatting.

Select the range you want to apply the Conditional Formatting to.
On the Home tab, click on Conditional Formatting > New Rule. 
On the New Formatting Rule pop-up, select the rule type "Format only cells that contain"
Edit the rule to have the following:

Cell Value > Not Equal To > =INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))

Change your format to whichever you desire.
[Here is a picture of what you should be looking at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcFs5.png)

To make the cells automatically color themselves if they equal the above, make another rule for the column following the same steps, using the same equation, but instead set the modifer to Equal To.

Your rules in the Conditional Formatting Rules page would look [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvs68.png)

Cheers!

Comment: After seeing Tim Williams answer, I reread the question and realized my answer may not fully answer the question. Tim's does exactly what the question asks, I think...